# entityManager.persist() working in servlet but not in separate class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to JPA and Hibernate. I'm trying to insert a `Thing` into my `Thing` table in my database using `entityManager.persist()`. When I do so inside a servlet, the `Thing` is added, but when I do so from a separate class, and call the method from the servlet, the `Thing` isn't added.

This works:

```
// servlet

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
@Resource
UserTransaction utx;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {

        Thing thing = new Thing("word");

        utx.begin();
        em.persist(thing);
        utx.commit();

    } catch (Exception ex) { }

}
```

But this doesn't:

```
// servlet

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Thing thing = new Thing("word");

    ThingDao thingDao = new ThingDao();
    thingDao.add(thing);

}
```

Given,

```
// ThingDao

public class ThingDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
    @Resource
    UserTransaction utx;

    public void add(Thing thing) {

        try {

            utx.begin();
            em.persist(thing);
            utx.commit();

        } catch (Exception ex) { }

    }

}
```

Why does the second method not work? How do I make it work?

Comment: `new ThingDao()` - creating the instance like this results in the container not knowing it exists and thus no injection can happen. Either let the container inject the instance into your servlet or do a lookup (of course it should be an injectable bean and you probably don't want CDI's Dependent scope)

Comment: Additionally you should realize that `catch (Exception ex) { }` is very dangerous. You'll most likely get a `NullPointerException` but since you don't even log the exception you never see it and thus have to wonder "why that thing isn't persisted" - logging the exception should have resulted in you realizing that `utx` and `em` in  `ThingDao` are null and that would have guided your question accordingly. - Take away: _don't use empty catch-blocks!_

Comment: try to send into ThingDao em too like `class ThingDao { public ThingDao(EntityManager em){ this.em=em;}` and in processRequest make `ThingDao thingDao = new ThingDao(em); thingDao.add(thing);`

Comment: @Dred tried what you suggested, didn't work. I did however modify the `add` method inside `ThingDao`, and called it using `thingDao.add(thing, em, utx)`, passing the EntityManager and UserTransaction in calling the method, and it now adds the record just fine! But having to pass `em` and `utx` in addition to `thing`... I wonder if there is another way to achieve this without having to do `em.persist(thing)` within the servlet itself.

Comment: Spring Helps you with that, or other DI ). I saw an answer about that

Comment: If you didn't use Spring, you can try to make Abstract class where you initialize your dataSource, then extend that class in your ThingDao. After that, it shouldn't be problem in servlet if you do correct

Answer (score 0):

Annote with @Component and autowire it because  there is no DI.

// ThingDao

```
@Compoenent
public class ThingDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
    @Resource
    UserTransaction utx;



    public void add(Thing thing) {

        try {

            utx.begin();
            em.persist(thing);
            utx.commit();

        } catch (Exception ex) { }

    }

}
```

//In servlet

```
       @Autowired
       ThingDao td;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Thing thing = new Thing("word");


    td.add(thing);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By studying code I'm figuring you are using Spring if so you're missing followings :

1. class ThingDao

   @Transactional
   @Repository
   public class ThingDao {
2. serverlet : you need to autowire ThingDao there

   @Autowired
   ThingDao td;

Hope it helps

Comment: I wasn't actually using Spring beforehand, only Hibernate. But I added the Spring Framework 4.0.1 library to my project (in NetBeans) and tried what you suggested. Still the same result.

Comment: have you tried set EntityManager em; and UserTransaction utx; from serverlet?

i.e. you need to create setter for em and utx in ThingDao and then set those in serverlet